# Redirect a wix website to a new external website

Tags: html, web, redirect

I just made a new website for an association and the client is asking me to redirect their old wixsite website to the new website
Did anyone have a solution to do that?
It's seems more complicated with non-wix site

(I don't know at all how wix work)
Hoping someone could give me some help :)

Answer (score 9):

I found a way to do the *redirect from Wix* to an external website.

From your site's Dashboard:

- go to **Settings > Advanced Pannel > Custom Code**
- press the **+ Add Custom Code** button.

From my understanding, you want to redirect the entire website so if a user lands on `/about` it will also get redirected to your new website. Just make sure you:

- select **All Pages** and **Load code on each new page**
- select to place code in **Body - start**.

Now, in the **code snippet** text field, paste this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.parent.location.href = "https://www.<your-new-sites-address>.com"
</script>
```

- Make sure you got everything right and press the **Apply** button

*Optional*: you can give this code snippet a **name** that might help you remember what this is all about (ex: *Redirect to my new website*)

Comment: for SEO support you need a 301 redirect

Comment: Good temporary solution. Then you can transfer the domain to a real registrar that offers free redirection tools which is ideal for SEO support (as @ekkis says).

Comment: This only seems to work if you have their premium plan ...

Comment: This works for me..sucks for SEO but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:

> 301 Redirects only work with custom domains. It is not possible to set up a 301 redirect from free Wix URLs to a premium site.

To set up a 301 redirect:

- Go to SEO Tools in your site's dashboard.
- Click URL Redirect Manager.
- Click + New Redirect.
- Select Single Redirect.

Note: If you want to update multiple pages which share the same path, you can select group redirect. Learn More

- Enter the old URL path you want to redirect from, (e.g., /about-us) under Old URL.
- Start typing the URL path of your new page and select it from the drop-down.
- Click Save & Close or click Save & Add Another to add more.

Here's what it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but so impossible to redirect to a non-wix website...? :/

Comment: @unpseudocoo I'm afraid so :(

Comment: this mechanism does not allow for redirecting the home page: /

Comment: This is a horrible feature. You can't redirect to another external domain :(

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Wix has a new way of accomplishing this:

Create a page for the route you want to redirect from.

Something like:

```
/zoom
```

Then go to that page and turn on `Dev Mode` and paste the following into the code box that appears at the bottom of the page:

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';

$w.onReady(function () {
    // Redirect to our link
    wixLocation.to("EXTERNAL LINK HERE");
});
```

Click Publish!

[Wix Documentation](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-location/to)

Comment: this is not SEO friendly as it does not generate 301 headers

Comment: Is this working for you? I tried this approach, but it doesn't redirect to external links, it only works with internal links.

Comment: this works for me with external links